# Prevent Google Drive to exclude cell protection parameters from Excel file

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm having some trouble in keeping protected ranges from Excel files in Google Drive.
[In this link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArSUqnb0D-mbg3HD5jyFORbCk8MC?e=qcrMPH) there is an original Excel file with a protected cell in OneDrive and in [this other link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ISIaY8AjEk9uf54jTT6_Q8t_O1V4mWv5/edit#gid=1441861319) is this very same file but in Google Drive. You can see that when I put the files in Google Drive it just kills the original protection from Excel. Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that both features are completely different and not compatible yet. Microsoft's cell protection feature works only when using Office. If you upload and open the document in Google Drive, Google does not have a way to read the protection included by Microsoft as Google implemented their own cell protection feature as well.

For example, Google's protection feature works similar to the sharing permissions, based in users and email addresses, while Microsoft's protection gets implemented within the document itself.

Google added a [compatibility mode](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9406611) for office documents not long ago, so it may be possible that this is available in the future, however at the moment there is no way to merge both protection features.

References:

- [Work with Microsoft Office files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308757)
- [Edit Office files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139)